# jQuery DataTables - Ordering dates by hidden column

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatables

I have been working for a couple of days with DataTables and I have this task:
I need to disable the initial sorting and filter the first column which contains dates like `Aug 15` depending on the fourth one (`2015.08.15`), which will be hidden.

For example, if I have:

```
Aug 15    |  2015.08.15
Aug 7     |  2015.08.07
Aug 3     |  2015.08.03
Aug 20    |  2015.08.20
```

In ascending sort I should get:

```
Aug 3     |  2015.08.03
Aug 7     |  2015.08.07
Aug 15    |  2015.08.15
Aug 20    |  2015.08.20
```

But I get the alphabetical sort:

```
Aug 15    |  2015.08.15
Aug 20    |  2015.08.20
Aug 3     |  2015.08.03
Aug 7     |  2015.08.07
```

My first code was something like:

```
$("#TableBt" + rid).DataTable({
  "aaSorting": [],
  "columns": [
    null,
    null,
    {
      "title": lC2
    },
    {
      "visible": false
    }]
```

This disabled my initial sorting, but it alphabetical sort my date column (the first and visible one).

After some research, I changed the code like this:

```
$("#TableBt" + rid).dataTable({
  "asSorting": [],
  "aoColumnDef": [
    {
      "iDataSort": 3,
      "aTargets": [4]
    },
    null,
    {
      "sTitle": lC2
    },
    {
      "bVisible": false,
      "aTargets": [3]
    }]
});
```

But now all the columns are visible, the initial sorting is again enable and the date sort works only alphabetical.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

You need to use [`columnDefs`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs) to target first column (`targets: 0`) and define the column which data would be used for sorting of the first column with [`orderData`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.orderData). Also you need to hide forth column (`targets: 3`) with `visible: false`.

```
$("#TableBt" + rid).DataTable({
   columnDefs: [
       { targets: 0, orderData: 3 },
       { targets: 3, visible: false }    
   ]
});
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yov3t42y/1/) for code and demonstration.