# How to sort date with dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm tt format in datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm currently working on datatable, I found my sorting for date column was not working. here was my screenshot

[image: datatable view]

Here was my code

```
<table id="tbl" class="table table-small-font table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th class="text-left">Dated</th>
      <th class="text-left">Day</th>
      <th class="text-center">Remarks</th>
      <th class="text-center">State</th>
      <th class="text-center"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @{ IEnumerable
    <PublicHoliday> PublicHolidays = (IEnumerable
      <PublicHoliday>)ViewData["PublicHolidays"]; int Idx = 1; } @foreach (var i in PublicHolidays) {
        <tr>
          <td>@Idx</td>
          <td>@i.Dated.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm tt")</td>
          <td>@i.Dated.ToString("ddd")</td>
          <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => i.Remarks)</td>
          <td>@i.ForStateName</td>
          <td><a data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete" onclick="DeleteRecord(@i.Id);"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a></td>
        </tr>
        Idx++; }
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var tbl = $('#tbl').DataTable({
      dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-6 col-xs-7'l><'col-sm-6 col-xs-7'f>>" + "rtip",
      order: [
        [0, "asc"]
      ],
      pagingType: "numbers",
      iDisplayLength: 50
    });
  });
</script>
```

the sort column does not work at all, and I can't find any plugin from datatable to use. anyone please help.. thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you can add a hidden column by convert date into timetamp(long), and the sort by it, ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32669709/9041712

Comment: @Yu-LinChen, I was going to suggest the same, I've done exactly this many times before, its easier to deal with a long.

Comment: May i know how the codes will be looks like?

Comment: @LeeYuanYee, I add the sample code below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47775236/9041712

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not really sure that there is any plugin that supports `date-dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm tt format`

So i have  made modification to the plugin to support this format.

Here is the code for it.Load this piece of code after loading the `datatable` plugin

```
   (function() {

       var customDateDDMMMYYYYToOrd = function(date) {
         var dateTime = date.split(' '),
           dateObj = new Date(dateTime[0].replace(/-/g, ' ')),
           time = "00:00",
           type = "AM";
         if (dateTime.length > 1) { // if time part and am/pm part is available
           time = dateTime[1],
             type = dateTime[2];
         }

         var splitTime = time.split(":"),
           hours = type == "PM" ? Number(splitTime[0]) + 12 : Number(splitTime[0]),
           minutes = Number(splitTime[1]),
           seconds = 0,
           milliseconds = 0;
         return new Date(dateObj.getFullYear(), dateObj.getMonth(), dateObj.getDate(), hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
       };

       // This will help DataTables magic detect the "dd-MMM-yyyy" format; Unshift
       // so that it's the first data type (so it takes priority over existing)
       jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.aTypes.unshift(
         function(sData) {
           "use strict"; //let's avoid tom-foolery in this function
           if (/^([0-2]?\d|3[0-1])-(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)-\d{4}/i.test(sData)) {
             return 'date-dd-mmm-yyyy';
           }
           return null;
         }
       );

       // define the sorts
       jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['date-dd-mmm-yyyy-asc'] = function(a, b) {
         "use strict"; //let's avoid tom-foolery in this function
         var ordA = customDateDDMMMYYYYToOrd(a),
           ordB = customDateDDMMMYYYYToOrd(b);
         return (ordA < ordB) ? -1 : ((ordA > ordB) ? 1 : 0);
       };

       jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['date-dd-mmm-yyyy-desc'] = function(a, b) {
         "use strict"; //let's avoid tom-foolery in this function
         var ordA = customDateDDMMMYYYYToOrd(a),
           ordB = customDateDDMMMYYYYToOrd(b);
         return (ordA < ordB) ? 1 : ((ordA > ordB) ? -1 : 0);
       };

     })();
```

The above code is the modification of [date sort plugin(`dd-mmm-yyyy`)](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/date-dd-MMM-yyyy).I have modified the `customDateDDMMMYYYYToOrd`  function to fit this specific example

Add this so that the plugin would know what to be use when date is sorted

```
   var tbl = $('#tbl').DataTable({
    dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-6 col-xs-7'l><'col-sm-6 col-xs-7'f>>" + "rtip",
    order: [[0, "asc"]],
    pagingType: "numbers",
    pageLength: 50,
    columnDefs: [
      { type: 'date-dd-mmm-yyyy', targets: 1 } //add this part
    ]   
});
```

You can find the list of sorting plugins available for `datatable` [here](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/)

Note:

> Please note that this plug-in is **deprecated*. The [datetime](https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18)
>   plug-in provides enhanced functionality and flexibility

Comment: may i know if there is two different date format in one datatable. how u will handle it?
one date format is dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm tt and another one is dd-MMM-yyyy

Comment: @LeeYuanYee Will modify the code that it sorts if hh:mm part is empty

Comment: How will it be looks like?

Comment: @LeeYuanYee . Modified.Please check.

Comment: i think i found the way now. THANK YOU SO SO SO SO MUCH!!! IT WORKS!!!!

Comment: I do have abit confused on the if statement, isn't it will always be true neither the time part was present or not.

Comment: Nope it wont.So here am trying to split it by space.Normal case it would be dd -MMM -yyyy hh:mm tt and it would get split into 3.Now in our special case it would only have dd-MMM-yyyy part

Answer (score 2):

Since `02-Jan-2017 12:00 AM` and so on is valid RFC2822 dates, all you have to do is to set the column `type` to `date` :

```
columnDefs: [
  { targets: 1, type: 'date' }
]
```

Or if you have some odd values in the data, like `null` values you can just pass back the parsed value and sort as number, by that forcing correct sorting anyway (I guess that is the real problem) :

```
columnDefs: [
  { targets: 1, 
    type: 'num',
    render: function(data,type) {
      if (type == 'sort') return Date.parse( data ).valueOf() 
      return data
    }
  }
]
```

There is really no need for a special sorting plugin here. A third option is to set the unformatted date as `data-sort` attribute on the  itself

```
<td data-sort="@i.Dated.ToString()">@i.Dated.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm tt")</td>
```

Comment: Sir,Date.parse('02-Jan-2017 12:00 AM') is not working in ie 11 and not in FF 57(Quantum).It is working in Chrome though

Answer (score 0):

I use momentjs and lodash, it would like:

```
var records = [
    ["1", "28-Jan-2017 12:00 AM"],
    ["1", "28-May-2017 12:00 AM"],
    ["1", "28-Mar-2017 12:00 AM"]
];

records = _.map(records, record => {
    record.push(moment(record[1], "DD-MMM-YYYY hh:mm A").unix());
    return record;
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        data: records,
        columns: [
            { title: "id" },
            { title: "date" },
            { title: "ts"}
        ],
        'columnDefs': [
            { 'orderData':[2] },
            {
              'targets': [2],
              'visible': false
            },
        ],
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        data: records,
        columns: [
            { title: "id" },
            { title: "date" },
            { title: "ts"}
        ],
        'columnDefs': [
                    { 'orderData':[2] },
                    {
                    'targets': [2],
                    'visible': false
                    },
                ],
    });
});
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g0y3d119/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following sorting method to your options to sort according to date and time , specially if your time in 12 hour(AM/PM) format. I use the following code and it works for me:

```
$('#tableid').DataTable({
                "order": [[, 'desc']],//order column in descending order.
                "columnDefs": [
                    { "type": "date", "targets":  }//date column formatted like "03/23/2018 10:25:13 AM".
                ],
                "pageLength": 25
            });
```