# jQuery datatable moment date format sorting plugin is not working for if I added "NA" or "---" as empty date value

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I used jQuery Datatable and the momentjs date format plugin of data table for date sorting in my application. Data table sorting is implemented for client site (sorting should happen in the DOM, not on request to the server and load data).
So, if I set an empty string as the value for one of the Data table `td` elements from date column, then it works fine, but when I set the value to 'NA' or '---' instead of an empty value then the sorting is not working properly.

```
Check code on jsfiddle
```

> https://jsfiddle.net/ranjit_redekar/b0p3qLtg/16/

**Not working when I use Any string (e.g '---')**

[image: Not working example]

**Sorting works when I use empty string**
[image: Working Example]

Comment: You will have to use a [hidden column](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/hidden_columns.html) to filter dates and output a "00/00/00" to filter correctly.

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32669709/2159528) for an example.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I went through you provided a link and you hide the date column in that example. I don't want to hide the column, my problem is sorting is not working on date field when one of the data table td value is '---' or NA.

Comment: Use two columns. Column A is your actual column with the "N/A" or "---" and column B is having "00/00/00" instead. Hide column B but use it to filter column A.

Comment: I'm not facing a problem with filtering, I'm facing a problem with column sorting.

Comment: I have updated question with screenshoots please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ordering based on dates works fine when there only is valid dates. If you have just one string somewhere in the column, DataTable falls back to the "normal" ordering method: as strings.

To walk around this issue, you will use a hidden column to order the visible one.

I adapted the code found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32669709/2159528) to your code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.fn.dataTable.moment('DD/MM/YY');

  $('.happyTable').DataTable({
    columnDefs: [
      { targets: 1, orderData: 2 },  // It says that column 1 will be ordered based on column 2
      { targets: 2, visible: false } // It says column 2 is hidden
    ]
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/sorting/datetime-moment.js"></script>

<table class="happyTable" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Hidden column</th><!-- Add a column here -->
    <th>ZIP</th>
    <th>Other</th>
  </tr>
    </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Merritt Molina</td>
    <td>26/12/15</td>
    <td>26/12/15</td><!-- When you have a valid date, use it -->
    <td>99266</td>
    <td>72341402999</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lamar Ryan</td>
    <td>24/09/16</td>
    <td>24/09/16</td>
    <td>91870</td>
    <td>04890349099</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Theodore Thornton</td>
    <td>14/10/16</td>
    <td>14/10/16</td>
    <td>76266</td>
    <td>22437000299</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Boris Harrell</td>
    <td>19/11/16</td>
    <td>19/11/16</td>
    <td>82000</td>
    <td>55735640699</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Oren Conner</td>
    <td>08/09/16</td>
    <td>08/09/16</td>
    <td>56717</td>
    <td>18666997199</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfonso Dawson</td>
    <td>---</td> <!-- visible, use any character you want -->
    <td></td> <!-- hidden, used to order. Leave empty -->
    <td>28491</td>
    <td>58270268699</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cole Perez</td>
    <td>24/08/15</td>
    <td>24/08/15</td>
    <td>54977</td>
    <td>26553861699</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>George Bauer</td>
    <td>10/12/15</td>
    <td>10/12/15</td>
    <td>26482</td>
    <td>54456979799</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Wing Summers</td>
    <td>10/02/16</td>
    <td>10/02/16</td>
    <td>83752</td>
    <td>29425569399</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bert Golden</td>
    <td>24/09/15</td>
    <td>24/09/15</td>
    <td>23673</td>
    <td>66513793199</td>
  </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to install a custom renderer for the values. That will make the sorting code see Date objects (so it will sort properly). The renderer will then handle the null / empty values displaying whatever string you want.

See https://datatables.net/manual/data/renderers