# How to order a DataTable using a hidden column

Tags: r, datatable, dt

I am rather new to R and I am trying to prepare an interactive data table using the DT package. My data contains numeric values, but some of these values are preceded by < or > sign. What I want is for my data table is to allow interactive sorting on the numeric values, regardless of whether there is a < or > sign in front of it. So for example >10, <5, 9, >8 should sort to <5, >8, 9, >10.

My initial approach for this was to duplicate the column containing the numeric values with < and > signs, to remove the < and > signs from this duplicate column, and to convert this data to numeric values to obtain a column with only the numeric values. What I then would like is to be able to order the data in the table on these numeric values, but I want to be able to do this when clicking the ordening button of the column containing the numeric values with the < and > signs. Therefore, I want to hide the column containing only the numeric values (since I do not want this column to be present in the table), but I want to somehow link the ordining function of the original column to this hidden column.

Here are some example data and a script in which I have already duplicated the column (b to c), removed the < and > signs, and converted it to numeric values to obtain the column c, which I have then hidden:

```
library(DT)

df <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=c('10','5.0','2.0','< 1.0','> 20'), c=c(10,5,2,1,20))
DT <- DT::datatable(df, 
                    options = list(columnDefs = 
                                   list(list(visible=FALSE, 
                                             targets=3))))
DT
```

I have not been able to find a way to sort the data in the table on this hidden column c by using the sorting button of column b.

I have found that this should be possible in JavaScript: [jQuery DataTables - Ordering dates by hidden column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32652292/jquery-datatables-ordering-dates-by-hidden-column)
However, I am not able to figure out how to do the same in R, either by using a suitable function in R, or by providing it in JavaScript using the JS() function.

Could anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `render`:

```
library(DT)

render <- c(
  "function(data, type, row){",
  "  if(type === 'sort'){",
  "    return parseFloat(data.match(/\\d+\\.?\\d+/)[0]);",
  "  }else{",
  "    return data;",
  "  }",
  "}"
)
df <- data.frame(
  a = 1:5, 
  b = c('10','5.0','2.0','< 1.0','> 20')
)
DT <- datatable(df, 
                options = list(
                  columnDefs = list(
                    list(render = JS(render), type = "num", targets = 2)
                  )
                )
)
DT
```

This solution does not require a hidden column.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! The solution by @Suliman is exactly what I was looking for with the hidden column, but to circumvent the use of the hidden column is also very neat. I will now figure out which of these two solutions suits my script best!

Answer (score 1):

```
library(DT)

df <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=c('10','5.0','2.0','< 1.0','> 20'), c=c(10,5,2,1,20))
DT <- DT::datatable(df, 
                    options = list(columnDefs = 
                                     list(list(visible=FALSE, targets=3),
                                          list(orderData=3, targets=2)
                                          )))
DT
```

Note: This answer is based on this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35657271/ordering-factors-in-data-table-using-dt-package), but `DT` now uses R indexing instead of JS indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it. To get the "sorting key" use `order`.

```r
library(DT)
# df <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=c('10','5.0','2.0','< 1.0','> 20'), c=c(10,5,2,1,20))
df <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = c('10', '5.0', '2.0', '< 1.0', '> 20'))
df
#ONE APPROACH
df$c <-
  stringr::str_replace(string = df$b,
                       pattern = "[<>]",
                       replacement = "") %>%
  as.numeric()
#ANOTHER APPROACH
df$c <- gsub("[<>]", "", df$b) %>% as.numeric()

DT::datatable(df[order(df$c), -3], rownames = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. While it does intially sort the data in the desired way when the table is first viewed, it unfortunately does not sort the data correctly when using the interactive sort button.